Unsupervised Segmentation methods for SAR satellite Images
Is there any unsupervised segmentation method (one that does not require model training) that yields optimal results on SAR images for classification. I have experimented with different thresholding method but they perform well only on certain images their results are inadequate when there is strong illumination or brightness. Could someone assist me in this matter?
Looking for a quick response. Thank you

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
